# Android Studio v 3.3 Giving error on building react native application

Tags: reactjs, android-studio, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am using `Android Studio v3.3` and I am facing issues with building and running the React Native project v0.57.

This error I am having on Android Studio while building is

```
    Android dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' has different version for the compile (27.1.1) and runtime (28.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

I have tried replacing `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` from `28.0.0` to `27.1.`1 and facing the same issue.

This is [my repo](https://github.com/Akashsystematix/todologinapp/tree/Redux-Development) for code in React native

Answer (score 2):

Try build with Android Studio 3.1 instead of 3.3. Because Android Studio 3.1 is suggested in React Native 0.57 release document.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#057

> Android tooling has been updated to match newer configuration
>   requirements (SDK 27, gradle 4.4, and support library 27); building
>   with Android plugin 3.2 doesn't work due to the gradle scripts, so
>   please stay on Android Studio 3.1 for now